# SQL Server : getting an 'Invalid Column Name' Error Message

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run a query to pull the total amount of qualifying events grouped by event type and month. For example I need to know that there were 25 "LOSS_OF_COVERAGE_NON_PAYMENT" qualifying events in January, and 10 "LEAVE_OF_ABSENCE" qualifying events in January. I have tried various SQL select queries. I am not sure why the query below is returning an error that states

> Invalid column name 'EventMonth'

My query:

```
SELECT 
    a.GroupID, c.employername, 
    MONTH(b.QualifyingEventDate) AS EventMonth, 
    b.QualifyingEventType
FROM 
    MST_MEMBER_DEMOGRAPHICS AS a 
JOIN
    DET_ENROLLMENT_DETAILS AS b ON a.BFUNIQUEID = b.BFUNIQUEID 
JOIN
    MST_EMPLOYER_GROUP_MASTER AS c ON a.groupid = c.groupid
WHERE 
    a.groupid = 'TESTClient' 
    AND QualifyingEventType <> 'NULL' 
    AND QualifyingEventDate BETWEEN '01/01/2019' AND '08/13/2019' 
GROUP BY 
    b.QualifyingEventType, EventMonth
ORDER BY 
    EventMonth, a.groupid, b.QualifyingEventType
```

Comment: Change `GROUP BY b.QualifyingEventType, EventMonth` to `GROUP BY b.QualifyingEventType, Month(b.QualifyingEventDate)` to resolve your error. Though, this probably still isn't the results you want since you aren't doing any aggregations but you state you want the "total amount" which usually implies using `SUM()`

Comment: You can't group by the alias, you would need to group by the derived value. Also, you can't group by only some of the non-aggregated columns. You have a few other issues here though. Your date literals are not ANSI compliant, they should be YYYYMMDD. Also, table aliases should have some context. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3 And be careful with 'NULL'. That is a string literal. You should instead put an actual NULL in the table, not a string that says 'NULL'.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses.  As you can probably tell I'ma bit lost here.  Unfortunately I don't have control over the data in the DB, I just need to query it.  So if I am looking to show the amount of each EventType per month how would I accomplish this?  How would I incorporate SUM() into my query?  I also need to create another query that does the same thing but also groups by EmployerName (removing the WHERE a.groupid = 'TESTClient' ).  What would that SQL statement look like? Thank you again for the help!